# Intuition re. log scale versus linear scale

Tags: error-analysis, statistics, diffusion, data-analysis

I have a dataset with the speed of movement of two sets of particles (the red, slower, and the blue, faster) as calculated by the diffusion constant.

Below is a histogram, on the left on linear scale and on the right on log scale.

[image: Linear versus Log scale]

I am trying to get some intuition for the log scale, including when it would be appropriate to use it. I am intrigued by the shape on the log scale of the particles, on log scale they seem to form perhaps a lognormal distribution, what does that mean? I am just trying to make sense of this: if the speed of particles form what looks like a normal distribution on the log scale, how should I interpret that, if at all? In general, not sure whether/if the shape of the distribution on log scale really means anything. Any insights or references to gain better understanding would be appreciated.

Comment: This is hard to answer because it depends on what you want to get from the data, or what kind of model you are using for the phenomenon.  I note that you created the histogram after taking the log. This may or may not be desirable.  You  might also want to take the log on the vertical scale.  One point of value that a log scale can give you is a better look at the very low (or high) values.  Your example shows that well.  Someone with more time than I will have to go into more detail.

Comment: This is very helpful @garyp, a little bit goes a long way!